# Google Glass: New CardSet oncklick

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-studio, google-glass

I'd like to open a new card "set" with a click in my application menu. At the moment, it reopens the same set of cards. I'd like to like open a new timeline and go back to my list whenever I swipe back. Please help me out of this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

// Define tag for debugging
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

//infocards
private List<CardBuilder> iCards;

// List of cards
private List<Card> mCards;

// ScrollView for holding cards
private CardScrollView mCardScrollView;

// Current card selected
private int currentCard = -1;

private List<StepsToCheck> mTaskList;
private ExampleCardScrollAdapter mAdapter;


private ExampleCardScrollAdapter adapter;
private CardScrollView iCardScrollView;
private ExampleCardScrollAdapter iAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the cards
    createCards();

    // Instantiate and set
    mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
    adapter = new ExampleCardScrollAdapter();

    mCardScrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCardScrollView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mCardScrollView.activate();

    // Set CardScrollView as content view
    setContentView(mCardScrollView);

}

// Instantiate ToDoListManager and get list
private void createCards() {


    mCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    CheckingStepManager listManager = new CheckingStepManager();

    mTaskList = listManager.getToDoList();

    Card card;

    int sizeList = mTaskList.size();

    // For all the cards
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeList; i++) {

        card = new Card(this);
        card.setText(mTaskList.get(i).getTask());

        // Set in the arrayList
        mCards.add(card);

    }

}

// Class to manage CardScrollView
private class ExampleCardScrollAdapter extends CardScrollAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getPosition(Object item) {
        return mCards.indexOf(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mCards.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return CardBuilder.getViewTypeCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return mCards.get(position).getItemViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mCards.get(position).getView(convertView, parent);
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Create options from "/res/menu/main.xml"
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    // Get id for detect what item was selected
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {

        case R.id.settings_1 : // Do something for setting 1
            // Remove currentCard
            mTaskList.remove(currentCard);
            mCards.remove(currentCard);     // Remove the current card selected from the list of Cards
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the adapter that needs to update the data
            break;
```

Here is the setting2 in my menu which does not work.

```
        case R.id.settings_2 :

            createInfoCards();

            iCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
            iAdapter = new ExampleCardScrollAdapter();
            iCardScrollView.setAdapter(iAdapter);
            iCardScrollView.activate();
            setContentView(iCardScrollView);
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createInfoCards() {
    iCards = new ArrayList<CardBuilder>();

    iCards.add(new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.TITLE)
            .addImage(R.drawable.image1)
            .setText("Fuselage Map"));

   iCards.add(new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT)
            .setText(String.format(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))));

}




@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Set current Card for menu option handle
    currentCard = position;

    openOptionsMenu();



}
```

}

Comment: what happens exactly? did you debug and did it went into the second case or doesn't it enter it at all? Do you get a error somewhere on your code?

Comment: No I don't get an error, it just opens the first "card set" again, without the menu function. But I would like to open a new set as mentioned. Could you help me?

Comment: Please try debugging it and so you know what exactly happens. if the case is even triggering.

to be able to debug on google glass you need to add android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(); to your code. I put it in the onCreate most of the time. Be sure to take it out again when you are done with debugging

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you'd like to have a different set of cards if option #2 is selected. To do this while also retaining the previous set of cards, I suggest that you start a new activity in switch case #2.

You will need to create this new activity and populate it with the desired cards. When you are in this new activity, swiping down on the D-pad will close that activity and bring you to your first activity.